# Any non-(char*) proper way to initialize void* from const string in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++

I was given with a MSVC project that doesn't worked with gcc. Particularly this error is interesting:

```
    void * str;
    str = "data"; // error
    str = (char*)"data"; // working
```

Error is: `Error: invalid conversion from ‘const void*’ to ‘void*’`, so g++ (gcc 4.x) treats the string as const void, but how that MSVC treats it!?

Strange question: is there any other way to make this code working on both compilers, without moving away from void type, using union's or *_cast's? (Please answer with standards, I want to give something to MSVC fans out there :))

Comment: Reminds me of [this](https://xkcd.com/541/)...

Comment: Both str = "data" and str = (char*)"data" work for me with gcc 4.4.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've pretty much answered your own question.  MSVC++ is, for compatibility's sake, allowing the same license that plain C does, to treat string literals as having type `char *` rather than `const char *`.  To make it work with gcc without fixing the types, you need to write `(char *)"data"` everywhere you have bare `"data"`.  If you don't like old-style casts, `const_cast<char *>("data")` should also work.

If you can change the types even a little, then as GMan says, `const void *` should do ya.

Answer (score 4):

Strings are arrays of constant characters. Such an array can be converted to `const char*`.

Note the const-qualifier: `const char*`, not `char*`. Converting a string literal to `char*` is a deprecated (removed in C++0x) and unsafe conversion. You should make your target `const void*`.

Comment: Note: conversion from `char const*` to `void*` is illegal. But conversion from `char const*` to `char*` is only deprecated. So the first is an error the second is only a warning. But still very bad.

Answer (score 2):

Don't treat C-strings as `void*`. Use `const char*` instead.

But if you *have* to for historical reasons, make it a const pointer: `const void* str = "data";`

Answer (score 1):

"data" is a literal of type const char[5], modifying a constant is undefined behaviour.

You could use a character array allocated on the stack:

```
char data[] = "example";
void* str = data;
```

But why are you trying to do this? There are much safer ways of dealing with text, i.e. std::string which implements RAII for you.